# Apply parameter control despite on filtering in tableau

Tags: parameters, filtering, reporting, tableau-api, dashboard

I want to find top N Customers based on some criterion. I've created parameter for that, but I want always to show that number of Customers and after I apply some filter.

For example: I've decided to find top 10 Customer from all of them, but i changed my mind and I just want to see top 10 from my Key Customers. After I use filter Tableau shows me seven top customers (seven of initial 10 was key Customers). How to create report to have this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a calculated filed =index()
2. Drag that onto your sheet, make it discrete
3. Filter index() for top 10

This link probably explains it better and in more detail:
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/finding-top-n-within-category

Comment: This approach can have a performance downside if there are many possible values for your Customer field. It queries the database and retrieves data for each customer, and only displays the results for the top 10 (leaving the rest fetched but hidden). Using a context filter instead does that computation in the database and only sends the top 10 results back to Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Make the filters that you want to apply first (i.e. take effect before calculating your top N) into ***context filters***.

You can do that by selecting those fields on the filter shelf and using the caret menu or right click to bring up a menu, and choosing "add to context".

You could also make them data source or extract filters, to make them take effect before your top N are computed -- but data source and extract filters can't be switched in the viz by a filter control. They are for filters that you want to apply widely in advance.